# MATLAB sparse matrices: Gauss Seidel and power method using a sparse matrix with CSR (Compressed Sparse Row)

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

this is my first time here so I hope that someone can help me.
 I'm trying to implementing the Gauss-Seidel method and the power method using a matrix with the storage CSR or called Morse storage. Unfortunately I can't manage to do better then the following codes:

GS-MORSE:

```
function [y] = gs_morse(aa, diag, col, row, nmax, tol)

[n, n] = size(A);

y = [1, 1, 1, 1];

m = 1;

while m < nmax,

    for i = 1: n,
        k1 = row(i);
        k2 = row(i + 1) - 1;
        for k = k1: k2,
            y(i) = y(i) + aa(k) * x(col(k));
            y(col(k)) = y(col(k)) + aa(k) * diag(i);
        end
        k2 = k2 + 1;
        y(i) = y(i) + aa(k) * diag(i);
    end
    if (norm(y - x)) < tol
        disp(y);
    end
    m = m + 1;
    for i = 1: n,
        x(i) = y(i);
    end
end
```

POWER-MORSE:
I was able only to implement the power method but I don't understand how to use the former matrix... so my code for power method is:

```
function [y, l] = potencia_iterada(A, v)

numiter=100;

eps=1e-10;

x = v(:);

y = x/norm(x);

l = 0;

for k = 1: numiter,

    x = A * y;
    y = x / norm(x);
    l0 = x.' * y;
    if abs(l0) < eps
      return
    end
    l = l0;
end
```

Please anyone can help me for completing these codes or can explain me how can I do that? I really don't understand how to do. Thank you very much